# Apex Trigger: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY data value too large: (value has been hidden):

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I keep getting the following error on either field CaseEmailAddress or Action Take on G2 and I have no idea why? My previous trigger was working I just added a couple new fields like first name, last name, web form phone. Code coverage is at 100%.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, GrabCaseDescriptionText: data changed by trigger for field Action Take on G2:: data value too large: (value has been hidden): []

OR

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, GrabCaseDescriptionText: data changed by trigger for field CaseEmailAddress: data value too large: (value has been hidden): []

This trigger will be looking at two different web submissions and getting sent to a case where I can create a lead from. I have 1 form from G2 (where its just using name) and another where the form submission is via first + last name.

I even updated my char limits for my text fields but that doesnt seem to be working.

Any help would be greatly apprecviated!

**Trigger**:

trigger GrabCaseDescriptionText on Case (before insert, before update)  {
for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
if (c.Description != null) {
List lines = new List();
lines = c.Description.split('\n');

```
     for (String line: lines) {
        if(line.contains('Email: ')){
            line.remove('Email: ');
            system.debug(line);
            c.CaseEmailAddress2__c = line.remove('Email: ');
        }
         if(line.contains('email: ')){
            line.remove('email: ');
            system.debug(line);
            c.CaseEmailAddress__c = line.remove('email: ');
        }
         if(line.contains('First name: ')){
            line.remove('First name: ');
            system.debug(line);
            c.First_Name__c = line.remove('First name: ');
        }
         if(line.contains('Last name: ')){
            line.remove('Last name: ');
            system.debug(line);
            c.Last_Name__c = line.remove('Last name: ');
        }
         if(line.contains('name: ')){
            line.remove('name: ');
            system.debug(line);
            c.Submitter_Name__c = line.remove('name: ');
        }
            if(line.contains('action takeN on G2: ')){
                line.remove('action takeN on G2: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Action_Take_on_G2__c = line.remove('action takeN on G2: ');
            }
            if(line.contains('industry: ')){
                line.remove('industry: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Industry__c = line.remove('industry: ');
            }
         if(line.contains('How many users are you looking to onboard?: ')){
                line.remove('How many users are you looking to onboard?: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Users_to_Onboard__c  = line.remove('How many users are you looking to onboard?: ');
         }
           if(line.contains('What service are you using today?: ')){
                line.remove('What service are you using today?: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Current_Device__c  = line.remove('What service are you using today?: ');
            }  
         if(line.contains('company size: ')){
                line.remove('company size: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Company_Size__c  = line.remove('company size: ');
            }
            if(line.contains('company: ')){
                line.remove('company: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Submitter_s_Company__c  = line.remove('company: ');
            }
            if(line.contains('phone number: ')){
                line.remove('phone number: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Submitter_s_Phone__c  = line.remove('phone number: ');
            }
         if(line.contains('Current phone number: ')){
                line.remove('Current phone number: ');
                system.debug(line);
                c.Web_Form_Phone__c  = line.remove('Current phone number: ');
            }  
            
        }
        if(c.CaseEmailAddress__c !=null){
            List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email=:c.CaseEmailAddress__c LIMIT 1];
            if(cons.size()>0)c.ContactId=cons[0].id;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class TestCaseComment {
    static testMethod void insertCase() {
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Status = 'New';
        c.Origin = 'Email';
        c.Description = 
        'email: a@abusa.com'+
        'Email: a@abusa.com' +
        'name: Christopher Martin'+ 
        'First name: Christopher' + 
        'Last name: Martin' + 
        'How many users are you looking to onboard?: 2 - 5'+ 
        'What service are you using today?: Personal device' +
        'phone number: 09090909'+
        'Current phone number: 09090909' +
        'company: Wake Wash'+
        'action takeN on G2: Requested'+
        'company size: 2-10 employees'+
        'industry: Consumer Services'+
        'lead submitted at: 2022-07-28T09:39:15.059-05:00';
        insert c;
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to put actual line breaks *inside* the strings:

```
c.Description = 
    'email: a@abusa.com\n'+
    'Email: a@abusa.com\n'+
    'name: Christopher Martin\n'+ 
    'First name: Christopher\n'+ 
    'Last name: Martin\n'+ 
    'How many users are you looking to onboard?: 2 - 5\n'+ 
    'What service are you using today?: Personal device\n'+
    'phone number: 09090909\n'+
    'Current phone number: 09090909\n'+
    'company: Wake Wash\n'+
    'action takeN on G2: Requested\n'+
    'company size: 2-10 employees\n'+
    'industry: Consumer Services\n'+
    'lead submitted at: 2022-07-28T09:39:15.059-05:00';
```

You may want to write your code to handle the situation where data is too large.

As a side note, note that the various lines, such as:

```
line.remove('company size: ');
```

Are pointless, as they do not modify the original string.

You might also want to use `startsWith` or maybe even `startsWithIgnoreCase`, since it seems possible that you'll miss data if the field labels change at all.